# Is there a HTML analyzer/tokenizer for Lucene?

Tags: lucene

I wanted to index text from html, in Lucene, what is the best way to achieve this ?
Is there any good Contrib module that can do this in Lucene ?

**EDIT**
Finally ended up using Jericho Parser. It doesn't create DOM and is easy to use.

Comment: This question is interesting. Converting to plain text before tokenizing could be a problem if it loses the natural delimiters that HTML tags provide. For example: `<li>New York</li><li>City of Chicago</li>` should not be tokenized as `New York City`, `of`, `Chicago` but that could happen it you convert it to `New York City of Chicago` first. Converting tag breaks to `\n` would probably help, but you have to be careful: do you do it with `<p>`? Probably. `<em>`? Probably not.

Comment: @DavidJames, Congratulations, you gave life to a year and half old thread :)  
Just google for "Jericho Parser", it solves the issue you defined anyway :)
Also, if you like the question, you can favorite it and upvote :)

Comment: Do you have the source for the tokenizer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm assuming that you don't actually want to index the HTML tags.  If that's the case, you can first extract text from HTML using [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/0.7/formats.html#HyperText_Markup_Language).  Then you can index the text in Lucene.

Comment: Any better, fast, light weight tool than Tika ? That does only text extraction part ?

Comment: You can try [htmlparser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/). Or use the same library that Tika uses, [TagSoup](http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/). But, if you ask me, I'd still use Tika.

Comment: @mbonaci : You'd still use Tika? Why ?? Reasons ?

Comment: There are tons of examples out there; it's not heavy-weight; I usually need more than HTML parser, or the need for other parsers arises later; it's reliable and OS; the both products are ASF, so they will always work well together...

Comment: @mbonaci, @bajafresh4life : If I wanted *only* extraction of text, and not the DOM and all other hassles, would it still be TIKA ?

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend using [Jsoup HTML parser](http://jsoup.org/) to extract the text and then use Lucene. It worked well for me.

Answer (score 2):

You might also want to take a look at /Lucene-3.0.3/src/demo which has an HTML parser example.

Comment: That was the first thing I saw, but believe me when I say, I need more than that to work with... :)