# Chaining a Solr HTMLStripCharFilter with a Lucene Analyzer

Tags: solr, lucene

I want to index Html text with the FrenchAnalyzer so I need to strip Html before analyzing it.

I want to highlight keywords after searching so [solution like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271810/is-there-a-html-analyzer-tokenizer-for-lucene) doesn't work because I want to preserve character position information.

I found the SolR HTMLStripCharFilter class which looks perfect but I am not able to chain it with the FrenchAnalyzer.

I tried to rewrite the FrenchAnalyzer but I don't know how to use HtmlStripCharFilter and it doesn't work as a standard Lucene filter.

I am using Lucene 3.5.0 without Solr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Analyzer subclass try to override initReader. You may want to add a stripHtml boolean param to your Analyzer's constructor and then use this conditional inside initReader.

```
/**
 * Override this if you want to add a CharFilter chain.
 */
@Override
protected Reader initReader(Reader reader) {
    if (stripHtml) {
        return new HTMLStripCharFilter(CharReader.get(reader));
    } else {
        return reader;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about trying something like that:

```
<analyzer>
  <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
  <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.ElisionFilterFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="French"/>
</analyzer>
```

Read more:

1. [HTMLStripCharFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory)
2. [SnowballPorterFilterFactory](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/analysis/SnowballPorterFilterFactory.html)
3. [Solr LanguageAnalysis - French](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LanguageAnalysis#French)

Comment: The problem is that I don't use Solr !